# About Predictive Analysis & Processing

Tags: algorithm, web

We are working on some web tool which requires lots of user inputs at different levels.

What i am looking is there to predict the pattern of the inputs and pre-fill / preselect the data before user is entering it.

Lets say for example in some interface we are asking user to select any color. But if user select red for x number of times it should automatically pre-fill for rest of the inputs.

We can do that easily by putting some specific interface level code. But i want to ask if there is any advanced algorithms / libraries available which we can use to do the same  or not.

Comment: can you please specify what kinds of input you are trying to predict, and what are your criteria for success? Why would a "sort the combo-box by most-chosen" approach not work?

Comment: Yes i need something like that but needed a dynamic approach as we need to implement in some kind of website builder so that if i am changing some background color then it should help me to show the updated color at few other places or it should say update it to x number of other places . So i know how to do it manually but i want some more better approach so that in future based on the current data i  should able to add my own login to the same.